# Dual boot Ubuntu 20 and Windows 10 broken after 2022 Bitlocker-forced update

Tags: dual-boot

I had dual boot working with Xubuntu 20 and Windows 10. A recent BIOS update in my ASUS Flow laptop forced Bitlocker back in (maybe linked to the recent Windows 10 update with the same effect). Nothing new, so luckily I had the key at hand, and after a lengthy C: decryption process I managed to enter Windows again and see the GRUB menu.

The GRUB menu works, and gives me the standard four options I've always had:

- Ubuntu
- Advanced options for Ubuntu
- Windows Boot Manager
- UEFI Firmware settings

I can access Windows and UEFI. But when selecting Ubuntu or Advanced options for Ubuntu, the system simply restarts, back to the GRUB.

From the BIOS, I've tried:

- Disabling SMART self Test
- Disabling fast boot (also from Windows Power options)
- Disabling secure boot

but the result stays the same.

I haven't tried yet a USB recovery, because I'm afraid that may break booting from Windows, as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911963/dual-boot-with-windows-10-broken-after-update).

(also, the laptop gets very hot when I enter the BIOS via GRUB. This does not happen when accessing the BIOS via Windows or post screen)

Comment: *"A recent BIOS update in my ASUS Flow laptop forced Bitlocker back in"* - What do you mean by this? These two things should not have anything to do with each other, and it's unclear how exactly a bitlocker issue caused your Ubuntu issue. *"laptop gets very hot when I enter the BIOS"* - This has nothing to do with Ubuntu or any other operating system. Only your UEFI firmware is being used. You don't mention using [boot-repair](https://askubuntu.com/a/182863) - this utility needs to be run from a liveUSB.

Comment: Hi NMath. The forced bitlocker update results in a screen that replaces GRUB and wouldn't let me access Ubuntu. I found the key and the GRUB screen shows again, but after that update Ubuntu will not start after selecting it. I don't know exactly how the forced-bitlocker update causes this, but I know that a broken dual-boot is a common issue on big Windows/BIOS updates. Will try the boot-repair to recover important data for now. (The hot laptop happens when accessing the BIOS via GRUB, and not via post or Windows. Updating the question. But it's indeed just a secondary issue for now).

Comment: Indeed, I phrased it poorly. Didn't mean cause-effect, but order of events with unknown cause. I tried boot-repair, but even then, when starting from the GRUB from the live USB, selecting any Ubuntu-related option results in a system restart, back to the same USB boot menu.

Comment: Do you mean you can't boot a USB either? Or are you saying that boot-repair didn't correct issue? If you were able to use boot-repair, please post the boot repair summary. You can use https://pastebin.ubuntu.com If you couldn't boot a USB, you should verify that the USB media is actually bootable. You can test this on another device. Or you can [verify the ISO download](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu) and flash the ISO to USB using balenaEtcher which will verify the flash. If you can't boot confirmed valid USB media, then the problem is with your motherboard, not Ubuntu

Comment: Is secure boot enabled in your motherboard or some other motherboard setting that would prevent you from booting some types of programs? If the motherboard firmware update wiped your settings you'll need to set them back up how you had it before the BIOS update. Motherboard firmware settings can prevent the booting of operating systems or change the boot priority, but neither of these things actually affect the installed operating systems themselves